# Any reason to use "while 1, do something, break" in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, sympy

In the Python library [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) I try to understand the function `partitions()` in [`sympy.utilities.iterables`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy%2Futilities%2Fiterables.py):

It starts like this:

```
def partitions(n, m=None, k=None, size=False):
    """Generate all partitions of integer n (>= 0).
```

I am confused about the following while loop, because it looks pointless. If I remove the `while 1:` and the `break` it should make no difference. However, I expect that the people who develop SymPy know what they are doing, and don't make very simple mistakes. So does this make some sense that I fail to see?

```
while 1:
    # Let i be the smallest key larger than 1.  Reuse one instance of i.
    i = keys[-1]
    newcount = ms[i] = ms[i] - 1
    reuse += i
    if newcount == 0:
        del keys[-1], ms[i]
    room += 1

    # Break the remainder into pieces of size i-1.
    i -= 1
    q, r = divmod(reuse, i)
    need = q + bool(r)
    if need > room:
        if not keys:
            return
        continue

    ms[i] = q
    keys.append(i)
    if r:
        ms[r] = 1
        keys.append(r)
    break
```

For learning purposes I have simplified the whole function, and `my_partitions(n)` gives the same results as `partitions(n)`.

```
def my_partitions(n):
    ms = {n: 1}
    keys = [n]
    yield ms

    while keys != [1]:
        # Reuse any 1's.
        if keys[-1] == 1:
            del keys[-1]
            reuse = ms.pop(1)
        else:
            reuse = 0

        # Let i be the smallest key larger than 1.  Reuse one instance of i.
        i = keys[-1]
        ms[i] -= 1
        reuse += i
        if ms[i] == 0:
            del keys[-1], ms[i]

        # Break the remainder into pieces of size i-1.
        i -= 1
        q, r = divmod(reuse, i)
        ms[i] = q
        keys.append(i)
        if r:
            ms[r] = 1
            keys.append(r)

        yield ms
```

Comment: it's ugly, but the reason for it has to do with the case when `need > room` (note the continue).

Comment: Pull requests to clean this up are welcome. The SymPy test suite has tests for this function so it should be clear if your implementation is wrong.

Comment: Obviously `my_partitions(n)` is not just a cleanup of `partitions(n, m, k, size)`. It just gives the same results for the same n.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a dirty hack to bring [goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) to Python.  The `while 1:` line is the label and the `continue` statement is the goto.

Please do not write code like that if you can avoid it.  If you *must* do this, at least make it `while True:` since the argument to `while` is ordinarily a boolean value.

Comment: It's probably a translation from Knuth.

Comment: Good point. If I want to understand things like SymPy, I should spend some time with TAOCP.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that `need > room && keys == True` you go to `continue`, which re-fires the `while` loop and does not `break` it. It seems pretty ugly, but it is necessary in this case (of course there should be alternatives).